# Add decimal value to a datetime datatype in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a datetime `2015-12-29 18:34:05.563` and i want to add 1.5 of decimal type so that the result should be `2015-12-29 20:00:05.563`

Comment: do you mean 1,5 hour ?

Comment: The difference between `18:34:05.563` and  `20:00:05.563` is 86 minutes. How you get from 1.5 to 86 minutes is a mystery to me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that 1.5 means 1 and a half hours, then for [TSQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx):

```
SELECT DateAdd( minute , 90, '2015-12-29 18:34:05.563')
```

Comment: In that case you don't get desired result.

Comment: I suspect a miscalculation in the desired result in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to add a decimal to a timestamp. You have to ask, "A decimal *what*--1.5 hours, 1.5 days?"

Standard SQL and PostgreSQL can use the interval data type for date arithmetic.

```
select timestamp '2015-12-29 18:00:00.000' + interval '1.5 hours';
"2015-12-29 19:30:00"

select timestamp '2015-12-29 18:00:00.000' + interval '1.5 hour';
"2015-12-29 19:30:00"
```

PostgreSQL will parse `'1.5' hour` without complaint, but you won't like the result. (Quoting the number, but not the units.)

```
select timestamp '2015-12-29 18:00:00.000' + interval '1.5' hour;
"2015-12-29 19:00:00"
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use [addTime](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime) function to edit the time in SQL

Comment: You answer is for `mySQL` not `SQL-Server` (see tags in the question).